# Can not find the file "ascii.afm" in ascii package zipfile

Tags: packages

In the section 2 of ascii package document "ascii2006.pdf" it said

```
2 Installation
The ascii package contains the following ﬁles:
ascii.dtx
ascii.ins
ASCII.afm

...
```

But I can not find the file ascii.afm. Does anyone can tell me how to get it?

Comment: It seems that the description is not current and indeed the AFM file doesn't exist. You can recover it with `pf2afm ASCII.pfb`; however it's not needed for TeX.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for hint. I've candled with it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the description of the package is not current and indeed the AFM file doesn't exist. You can recover it with

```
pf2afm ASCII.pfb
```

However the AFM file is not needed for TeX. Here's the output, anyway.

```
StartFontMetrics 2.0
Comment AFM Generated by Ghostscript/pf2afm
FontName ASCII
FullName ASCII
FamilyName ASCII
Weight Medium
Notice Copyright (c) 2006 Apostolos Syropoulos asyropoulos@yahoo.com
This program can be redistributed and/or modified under the terms
of the LaTeX Project Public License Distributed from CTAN
archives in directory macros/latex/base/lppl.txt; either
version 1 of the License, or any later version.
This program was created with FontForge 
http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/
ItalicAngle 0
IsFixedPitch false
UnderlinePosition -100
UnderlineThickness 50
Version 001.000
EncodingScheme FontSpecific
FontBBox 2 -232 522 783
StartCharMetrics 218
C 0 ; WX 525 ; N uni2400 ; B 58 60 467 546 ;
C 1 ; WX 525 ; N uni2401 ; B 16 0 509 493 ;
C 2 ; WX 525 ; N uni2402 ; B 16 0 509 493 ;
C 3 ; WX 525 ; N uni2403 ; B 23 -5 502 550 ;
C 4 ; WX 525 ; N uni2404 ; B 28 2 497 643 ;
C 5 ; WX 525 ; N uni2405 ; B 4 0 521 518 ;
C 6 ; WX 525 ; N uni2406 ; B 26 1 499 600 ;
C 7 ; WX 525 ; N uni2407 ; B 166 175 359 368 ;
C 8 ; WX 525 ; N uni2408 ; B 32 0 493 461 ;
C 9 ; WX 525 ; N uni2409 ; B 54 63 471 482 ;
C 10 ; WX 525 ; N uni240A ; B 10 -1 514 513 ;
C 11 ; WX 525 ; N uni240B ; B 48 120 477 571 ;
C 12 ; WX 525 ; N uni240C ; B 114 38 411 571 ;
C 13 ; WX 525 ; N uni240D ; B 103 14 421 571 ;
C 14 ; WX 525 ; N uni240E ; B 17 -21 509 576 ;
C 15 ; WX 525 ; N uni240F ; B 9 -1 516 507 ;
C 16 ; WX 525 ; N uni2410 ; B 18 73 508 420 ;
C 17 ; WX 525 ; N uni2411 ; B 18 73 508 420 ;
C 18 ; WX 525 ; N uni2412 ; B 125 -1 400 617 ;
C 19 ; WX 525 ; N uni2413 ; B 122 -3 404 621 ;
C 20 ; WX 525 ; N uni2414 ; B 40 -62 486 604 ;
C 21 ; WX 525 ; N uni2415 ; B 98 -112 427 634 ;
C 22 ; WX 525 ; N uni2416 ; B 6 130 519 287 ;
C 23 ; WX 525 ; N uni2417 ; B 125 -91 400 616 ;
C 24 ; WX 525 ; N uni2418 ; B 128 0 397 613 ;
C 25 ; WX 525 ; N uni2419 ; B 126 -2 399 624 ;
C 26 ; WX 525 ; N uni241A ; B 20 138 506 363 ;
C 27 ; WX 525 ; N uni241B ; B 20 139 506 364 ;
C 28 ; WX 525 ; N uni241C ; B 116 189 410 693 ;
C 29 ; WX 525 ; N uni241D ; B 19 132 506 363 ;
C 30 ; WX 525 ; N uni241E ; B 62 96 463 472 ;
C 31 ; WX 525 ; N uni241F ; B 62 97 463 473 ;
C 32 ; WX 525 ; N uni2420 ; B 44 -132 481 240 ;
C 33 ; WX 525 ; N exclam ; B 212 0 312 622 ;
C 34 ; WX 525 ; N quotedbl ; B 130 328 396 622 ;
C 35 ; WX 525 ; N numbersign ; B 36 0 490 611 ;
C 36 ; WX 525 ; N dollar ; B 58 -83 467 694 ;
C 37 ; WX 525 ; N percent ; B 36 -83 490 694 ;
C 38 ; WX 525 ; N ampersand ; B 32 -11 494 622 ;
C 39 ; WX 577 ; N quoteright ; B 206 238 371 547 ;
C 40 ; WX 525 ; N parenleft ; B 130 -82 394 694 ;
C 41 ; WX 525 ; N parenright ; B 130 -82 395 694 ;
C 42 ; WX 525 ; N asterisk ; B 68 90 456 521 ;
C 43 ; WX 525 ; N plus ; B 38 81 486 531 ;
C 44 ; WX 525 ; N comma ; B 180 -139 346 125 ;
C 45 ; WX 525 ; N hyphen ; B 56 271 468 341 ;
C 46 ; WX 525 ; N period ; B 200 0 325 125 ;
C 47 ; WX 525 ; N slash ; B 58 -83 466 694 ;
C 48 ; WX 525 ; N zero ; B 50 -11 475 622 ;
C 49 ; WX 525 ; N one ; B 94 0 431 622 ;
C 50 ; WX 525 ; N two ; B 52 0 473 622 ;
C 51 ; WX 525 ; N three ; B 44 -11 481 622 ;
C 52 ; WX 525 ; N four ; B 30 0 496 623 ;
C 53 ; WX 525 ; N five ; B 52 -11 473 611 ;
C 54 ; WX 525 ; N six ; B 54 -11 471 622 ;
C 55 ; WX 525 ; N seven ; B 44 -11 480 627 ;
C 56 ; WX 525 ; N eight ; B 44 -11 481 622 ;
C 57 ; WX 525 ; N nine ; B 54 -11 472 622 ;
C 58 ; WX 525 ; N colon ; B 200 0 325 431 ;
C 59 ; WX 525 ; N semicolon ; B 188 -139 338 431 ;
C 60 ; WX 525 ; N less ; B 56 56 468 556 ;
C 61 ; WX 525 ; N equal ; B 38 195 486 417 ;
C 62 ; WX 525 ; N greater ; B 56 56 468 556 ;
C 63 ; WX 525 ; N question ; B 62 0 463 617 ;
C 64 ; WX 525 ; N at ; B 55 -76 470 633 ;
C 65 ; WX 525 ; N A ; B 28 0 498 623 ;
C 66 ; WX 525 ; N B ; B 33 0 492 611 ;
C 67 ; WX 525 ; N C ; B 40 -11 484 622 ;
C 68 ; WX 525 ; N D ; B 30 0 495 611 ;
C 69 ; WX 525 ; N E ; B 24 0 501 611 ;
C 70 ; WX 525 ; N F ; B 32 0 493 611 ;
C 71 ; WX 525 ; N G ; B 34 -11 492 622 ;
C 72 ; WX 525 ; N H ; B 22 0 502 611 ;
C 73 ; WX 525 ; N I ; B 79 0 446 611 ;
C 74 ; WX 525 ; N J ; B 59 -11 466 611 ;
C 75 ; WX 525 ; N K ; B 28 0 497 611 ;
C 76 ; WX 525 ; N L ; B 34 0 491 611 ;
C 77 ; WX 525 ; N M ; B 18 0 508 611 ;
C 78 ; WX 525 ; N N ; B 28 0 496 611 ;
C 79 ; WX 525 ; N O ; B 56 -11 468 622 ;
C 80 ; WX 525 ; N P ; B 36 0 489 611 ;
C 81 ; WX 525 ; N Q ; B 56 -139 468 622 ;
C 82 ; WX 525 ; N R ; B 12 -11 513 611 ;
C 83 ; WX 525 ; N S ; B 52 -11 472 622 ;
C 84 ; WX 525 ; N T ; B 26 0 499 611 ;
C 85 ; WX 525 ; N U ; B 4 -11 520 611 ;
C 86 ; WX 525 ; N V ; B 18 -8 506 611 ;
C 87 ; WX 525 ; N W ; B 12 -8 514 611 ;
C 88 ; WX 525 ; N X ; B 28 0 497 611 ;
C 89 ; WX 525 ; N Y ; B 20 0 506 611 ;
C 90 ; WX 525 ; N Z ; B 46 0 479 611 ;
C 91 ; WX 525 ; N bracketleft ; B 132 -83 393 694 ;
C 92 ; WX 525 ; N backslash ; B 58 -83 466 694 ;
C 93 ; WX 525 ; N bracketright ; B 132 -83 393 694 ;
C 94 ; WX 525 ; N asciicircum ; B 100 471 424 611 ;
C 95 ; WX 525 ; N underscore ; B 56 -95 468 -25 ;
C 96 ; WX 577 ; N quoteleft ; B 205 238 371 547 ;
C 97 ; WX 525 ; N a ; B 28 -6 497 440 ;
C 98 ; WX 525 ; N b ; B 24 -6 501 611 ;
C 99 ; WX 525 ; N c ; B 66 -6 459 440 ;
C 100 ; WX 525 ; N d ; B 24 -6 500 611 ;
C 101 ; WX 525 ; N e ; B 58 -6 467 440 ;
C 102 ; WX 525 ; N f ; B 65 0 460 617 ;
C 103 ; WX 525 ; N g ; B 22 -229 502 442 ;
C 104 ; WX 525 ; N h ; B 12 0 512 611 ;
C 105 ; WX 525 ; N i ; B 74 0 451 612 ;
C 106 ; WX 525 ; N j ; B 102 -228 422 612 ;
C 107 ; WX 525 ; N k ; B 19 0 506 611 ;
C 108 ; WX 525 ; N l ; B 58 0 467 611 ;
C 109 ; WX 525 ; N m ; B 2 0 522 437 ;
C 110 ; WX 525 ; N n ; B 12 0 512 437 ;
C 111 ; WX 525 ; N o ; B 58 -6 468 440 ;
C 112 ; WX 525 ; N p ; B 24 -222 501 437 ;
C 113 ; WX 525 ; N q ; B 14 -222 511 437 ;
C 114 ; WX 525 ; N r ; B 35 0 490 437 ;
C 115 ; WX 525 ; N s ; B 69 -6 456 440 ;
C 116 ; WX 525 ; N t ; B 50 -6 475 554 ;
C 117 ; WX 525 ; N u ; B 12 -6 512 431 ;
C 118 ; WX 525 ; N v ; B 24 -4 500 431 ;
C 119 ; WX 525 ; N w ; B 16 -4 508 431 ;
C 120 ; WX 525 ; N x ; B 28 0 497 431 ;
C 121 ; WX 525 ; N y ; B 26 -228 500 431 ;
C 122 ; WX 525 ; N z ; B 42 0 483 431 ;
C 123 ; WX 525 ; N braceleft ; B 58 -83 468 694 ;
C 124 ; WX 525 ; N bar ; B 228 -83 298 694 ;
C 125 ; WX 525 ; N braceright ; B 58 -83 468 694 ;
C 126 ; WX 525 ; N asciitilde ; B 88 491 438 611 ;
C 127 ; WX 525 ; N uni2421 ; B 33 0 492 574 ;
C 160 ; WX 525 ; N uni00A0 ; B 29 2 496 605 ;
C 161 ; WX 525 ; N afii64937 ; B 174 321 335 629 ;
C 162 ; WX 525 ; N afii57929 ; B 182 332 343 640 ;
C 163 ; WX 525 ; N sterling ; B 21 0 504 588 ;
C 166 ; WX 525 ; N brokenbar ; B 236 2 289 566 ;
C 167 ; WX 525 ; N section ; B 98 -112 427 634 ;
C 168 ; WX 525 ; N dieresis ; B 112 540 413 640 ;
C 169 ; WX 525 ; N copyright ; B 4 -13 522 506 ;
C 171 ; WX 525 ; N guillemotleft ; B 58 -10 467 442 ;
C 172 ; WX 525 ; N logicalnot ; B 50 141 474 395 ;
C 173 ; WX 525 ; N uni00AD ; B 56 271 468 341 ;
C 175 ; WX 525 ; N afii00208 ; B 15 271 510 341 ;
C 176 ; WX 525 ; N degree ; B 169 423 356 612 ;
C 177 ; WX 525 ; N plusminus ; B 38 -1 486 551 ;
C 178 ; WX 525 ; N uni00B2 ; B 157 311 368 623 ;
C 179 ; WX 525 ; N uni00B3 ; B 153 308 372 625 ;
C 180 ; WX 525 ; N tonos ; B 200 473 326 613 ;
C 181 ; WX 525 ; N dieresistonos ; B 145 473 381 613 ;
C 182 ; WX 525 ; N Alphatonos ; B 28 0 498 652 ;
C 183 ; WX 525 ; N periodcentered ; B 200 306 325 431 ;
C 184 ; WX 525 ; N Epsilontonos ; B 16 0 509 640 ;
C 185 ; WX 525 ; N Etatonos ; B 19 0 505 641 ;
C 186 ; WX 525 ; N Iotatonos ; B 35 1 490 640 ;
C 187 ; WX 525 ; N guillemotright ; B 59 -10 467 442 ;
C 188 ; WX 525 ; N Omicrontonos ; B 25 -10 500 651 ;
C 189 ; WX 525 ; N onehalf ; B 26 0 499 586 ;
C 190 ; WX 525 ; N Upsilontonos ; B 25 1 500 651 ;
C 191 ; WX 498 ; N Omegatonos ; B 18 1 479 651 ;
C 193 ; WX 525 ; N Alpha ; B 28 0 498 652 ;
C 194 ; WX 525 ; N Beta ; B 33 1 492 641 ;
C 195 ; WX 525 ; N Gamma ; B 33 1 491 641 ;
C 196 ; WX 525 ; N uni0394 ; B 34 0 490 652 ;
C 197 ; WX 525 ; N Epsilon ; B 24 0 502 640 ;
C 198 ; WX 525 ; N Zeta ; B 45 1 479 640 ;
C 199 ; WX 525 ; N Eta ; B 21 0 504 641 ;
C 200 ; WX 525 ; N Theta ; B 57 -10 469 651 ;
C 201 ; WX 525 ; N Iota ; B 79 1 446 640 ;
C 202 ; WX 525 ; N Kappa ; B 28 0 498 641 ;
C 203 ; WX 525 ; N Lambda ; B 29 0 496 652 ;
C 204 ; WX 525 ; N Mu ; B 17 1 508 640 ;
C 205 ; WX 525 ; N Nu ; B 28 0 497 641 ;
C 206 ; WX 525 ; N Xi ; B 33 1 492 640 ;
C 207 ; WX 525 ; N Omicron ; B 57 -10 469 651 ;
C 208 ; WX 525 ; N Pi ; B 21 0 504 641 ;
C 209 ; WX 525 ; N Rho ; B 35 1 491 640 ;
C 211 ; WX 525 ; N Sigma ; B 40 1 484 640 ;
C 212 ; WX 525 ; N Tau ; B 26 1 498 640 ;
C 213 ; WX 525 ; N Upsilon ; B 38 1 488 651 ;
C 214 ; WX 525 ; N Phi ; B 41 1 484 640 ;
C 215 ; WX 525 ; N Chi ; B 27 0 498 641 ;
C 216 ; WX 525 ; N Psi ; B 38 1 488 640 ;
C 217 ; WX 525 ; N uni03A9 ; B 32 1 492 650 ;
C 218 ; WX 525 ; N Iotadieresis ; B 78 1 446 783 ;
C 219 ; WX 525 ; N Upsilondieresis ; B 37 1 487 783 ;
C 220 ; WX 525 ; N alphatonos ; B 21 -5 505 613 ;
C 221 ; WX 525 ; N epsilontonos ; B 45 -10 481 613 ;
C 222 ; WX 525 ; N etatonos ; B 31 -232 493 613 ;
C 223 ; WX 525 ; N iotatonos ; B 159 -5 366 613 ;
C 224 ; WX 525 ; N upsilondieresistonos ; B 45 -5 481 668 ;
C 225 ; WX 525 ; N alpha ; B 21 -5 505 437 ;
C 226 ; WX 525 ; N beta ; B 44 -232 480 646 ;
C 227 ; WX 525 ; N gamma ; B 38 -177 488 437 ;
C 228 ; WX 525 ; N delta ; B 47 -5 478 635 ;
C 229 ; WX 525 ; N epsilon ; B 45 -10 481 441 ;
C 230 ; WX 525 ; N zeta ; B 47 -133 478 651 ;
C 231 ; WX 525 ; N eta ; B 31 -232 493 442 ;
C 232 ; WX 525 ; N theta ; B 47 -5 479 646 ;
C 233 ; WX 525 ; N iota ; B 166 -5 358 437 ;
C 234 ; WX 525 ; N kappa ; B 45 -13 480 445 ;
C 235 ; WX 525 ; N lambda ; B 30 -5 495 642 ;
C 236 ; WX 525 ; N mu ; B 22 -227 503 442 ;
C 237 ; WX 525 ; N nu ; B 37 -5 487 441 ;
C 238 ; WX 525 ; N xi ; B 46 -132 478 651 ;
C 239 ; WX 525 ; N omicron ; B 42 -5 483 437 ;
C 240 ; WX 525 ; N pi ; B 32 -5 493 431 ;
C 241 ; WX 525 ; N rho ; B 44 -221 481 438 ;
C 242 ; WX 525 ; N sigma1 ; B 44 -110 481 437 ;
C 243 ; WX 525 ; N sigma ; B 47 -5 478 437 ;
C 244 ; WX 525 ; N tau ; B 40 -5 485 431 ;
C 245 ; WX 525 ; N upsilon ; B 45 -5 481 442 ;
C 246 ; WX 525 ; N phi ; B 37 -232 487 443 ;
C 247 ; WX 525 ; N chi ; B 40 -229 486 439 ;
C 248 ; WX 525 ; N psi ; B 44 -232 480 651 ;
C 249 ; WX 525 ; N omega ; B 33 -5 491 442 ;
C 250 ; WX 525 ; N iotadieresis ; B 86 -5 439 640 ;
C 251 ; WX 525 ; N upsilondieresis ; B 45 -5 481 640 ;
C 252 ; WX 525 ; N omicrontonos ; B 42 -5 483 613 ;
C 253 ; WX 525 ; N upsilontonos ; B 45 -5 481 613 ;
C 254 ; WX 525 ; N omegatonos ; B 33 -5 491 613 ;
C -1 ; WX 500 ; N space ; B 0 0 0 0 ;
EndCharMetrics
EndFontMetrics
```